# Can't find sdk\lib\library.lib

Tags: c++, c, opencv

This particular issue is caused by specifying a dependency to a lib file that had spaces in its path. The path needs to be surrounded by quotes for the project to compile correctly.

On the **Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input** tab of the project’s properties, there is an **Additional Dependencies** property. This issue was fixed by changing this property from:

```
C:\Program Files\sofware sdk\lib\library.lib
```

to:

```
" C:\Program Files\sofware sdk\lib\library.lib"
```

but after compiling, it says:

> Error  1   fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'sdk\lib\library.lib'

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are yo using Visual Studio? What version?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the path to your linker path and just the 'library.lib' name to your libs.